# Creating a file using parameters of other file using UNIX Shell Script

Tags: shell, unix

I have a series of files

```
484_mexico_201401.dat
484_mexico_201402.dat
484_mexico_201403.dat
```

… so on

I want to make files

`484_mexico_201401.mft`  which will have below containt

`484` `|` *datfile name* `|` *line count for the `.dat` file*

**Example:**

```
484|484_mexico_201401.dat|6000
```

can anyone help with a shell script for this ?

Comment: Have you tried anything already?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try `bash`,

```
for file in 484_*
do 
   new_file=${file%.*}; 
   echo "$(sed 's/^\([^_]\+\)_.*/\1/'<<<$file)|$file|$(wc -l $file|cut -d' ' -f1)" > "$new_file.mft"; 
done
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also try this.

```
location="./";for file in $(ls $location);do echo "$(echo $file|cut -d '_' -f 1)|$file|$(wc -l $file | cut -d ' ' -f 1)" >> output.txt;done
```

Then you will be able to read the new file buy typing cat output.txt

If you want to full script for it, then you may need to add the #!/bin/bash to the first line in the script.

```
#!/bin/bash
location="./";for file in $(ls $location);do echo "$(echo $file|cut -d '_' -f 1)|$file|$(wc -l $file | cut -d ' ' -f 1)" >> output.txt;done
```

save that into a file where you want the script to be then run `chmod 555 scriptname.sh` and you should be able to run.